# Raspberry Pi4 with Planar PCT2235 touch screen monitor

Tags: touchscreen

I'm fairly new to the raspberry pi world and I have a Planar PCT2235 22"touch screen that I would like to use with my raspberry pi4. The display works and the touch function sees the touch of my finger, but the pointer arrow and were it's press is registering on the monitor is about 3" away from my finger. Is there some kind of calibration that needs to be done or a driver that needs to be loaded. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: The user manual does not mention how to calibrate the touch thing.  Questions: (1) Do you have the user Guide for Rpi4B? (2) Where do you download the driver for Rpi4B?  My learning Notes: https://penzu.com/p/7dbe461d

Comment: USB touchscreens generally do not require model specific drivers as the interface is standardized/generic.

Comment: Have you done anything with xinput-calibrator to set the boundaries of your touchscreen?

Answer (score 0):

The Planar has a built in calibration tool. Just google it for your model number and it should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It does have a calibration tool but only for windows, so unless you are planning to get windows into your Raspberry Pi that won't work.